# MongoDB Sink Connector : Message truncated in Apache Kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm facing a problem with the MongoDB Kafka Connector.
I'm trying to produce a json message from console producer (and console consumer) into a Kafka Topic.

When the message is less size is less than 4096 Bytes, it is consumed properly. But when the message is larger than 4096 Bytes, I get this exception :

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=scraper-mongo-sink-0} Error converting message value in topic 'rawdata' partition 0 at offset 154 and timestamp 1636471830852: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
.......
.......

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
 at [Source: (byte[])"{ ........."[truncated 3595 bytes]; line: 1, column: 4096]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
 at [Source: (byte[])"{ "....[truncated 3595 bytes]; line: 1, column: 4096]
```

Does anyone have a clue what is causing this error ?  And more importantly, how to solve this issue ?

NB. I've tried modifying some default properties of the broker, as well as producer/consumer such as : offset.metadata.max.bytes, max.request.size, message.max.bytes, fetch.max.bytes
n, etc.

Please anyone help

Comment: IIRC, the console producer might be truncating data. There would therefore be nothing to fix on the connector side

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So If I understand correctly, what I'm trying to do would not work via a console producer ? Should instead develop a producer otherwise, or is there a solution to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish via console producer ?

Comment: One suggestion would be use shell redirection `kafka-console-producer ... < data.json` (make sure there is one JSON object per line). Or you can use `kcat` CLI tool instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `kcat` tool instead, but I vaguely remember coming across this issue before and I probably looked at the source code, but in any case, the alternative is to use input redirection from the shell rather than type (or paste) that much data. (If you are pasting, then the problem is either the clipboard, or the terminal, not Kafka)

```
kafka-console-producer ... < data.json
```

Make sure there is one JSON object/array/value per line